# Most Pythonic way to remove special characters from rows in a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I call `df.head()` on my Pandas dataframe, I get the following:

```
0                                          New YorkÊ
1                                       Los AngelesÊ
2                                           ChicagoÊ
3                                            LondonÊ
4                                           HoustonÊ
Name: cities, dtype: object
```

As you can see, there is an extra character of some sort at the end of the `cities` column.  So, I remove this character with the following code:

```
df['cities'] = df['cities'].str.replace('Ê', '')
```

This works.  But, is this the best (most Pythonic) way to remove this character?

Thanks!

Comment: Ideally, one figures out how they got there in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing's wrong with your solution per se, but you might be better off applying an overall `solution` for all non-ascii characters

```
>>> df['cities'] = df['cities'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii')
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a city name includes that character? A safer method is

```
df['cities'] = df['cities'].str.rstrip('Ê')
```

although it may still be messy if you have a capitalized city name ending in that character. But the risk is reduced.